# How can I load a web page to UIWebView using AFNetworking in ios

Tags: ios, uiwebview, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I want to load a web page to my UIWebView using AFNetworking. I have already imported AFNetworking libraries to my project and used to load images.
I want a code to load web page.hope your help.thank you!.

this is how I load images.it works fine.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    HomeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"homereuseIdentifier"];
    Home *mogoHome = [homepost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *homeimageurlname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", mogoHome.homeImage];
    NSURL *homeimageurl = [NSURL URLWithString:homeimageurlname];

    cell.hometitleLabel.text = mogoHome.homeTitle;
    [cell.homeimageView setImageWithURL:homeimageurl placeholderImage:nil];
    cell.timeLabel.text = [[mogoHome.modifiedTime componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1];
    return cell;
}
```

**but I used normal way to load web page**

```
NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.home.homewebUrl];
    NSURL *finalurl = [NSURL URLWithString:finalString];
    NSURLRequest *finalReques = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:finalurl];
    [self.finalwebView loadRequest:finalReques];
```

Comment: @anuk--  if you show your tried code it is easy to solve the issue

Comment: do you mean that you want AF to download the html and show it in UIWebView instead of loading the html in UIWebView?

Comment: yes @Toni lee I want to load using AF

Comment: where you want this means u need if user click the label or button or uitableviewcell

Comment: in my app when user clicks on a tableviewcell it appear another view with UIWebView. at that point I want to use this. now I'm using it normally, that I have showed in the code @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can understand You cant.!
If you want to show any content (HTML or anything web based) in a UIWebView, then you have to do it by NSURL only. With AFNetworking you can download the HTML file (If its a file), But the loading process in a UIWebview will have to be implemented by the ones apple provided us, Yes it will take a bit of time, but If you want optimisation then dont use a UIWebview

Comment: Instead of that what should I use @Saheb Roy

Comment: If you want to avoid the lag, i think the best thing would be download the entire content and display those in a customised ViewController, but that only workds if u already know how the content will be. but that would be a lot of work.. and much slower, or u can open the page in safari after clicking on the cell, that way user cant do anything about it.

or you are stuck with using webview

Comment: ok I will try with that. thanx for your suggestion. @Saheb Roy